# Formal GAGA and étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a $p$-adic flat formal scheme over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, whose special fiber has an ample line bundle. Then $\mathfrak{X}$ is algebraizable, that is there exists an algebraic $\mathbf{Z}_p$-scheme $X$ such that its $p$-adic formal completion is canonically isomorphic to $\mathfrak{X}$ as a $p$-adic formal scheme, and is unique up to isomorphism.

Grothendieck's Formal Existence Theorem implies the formal completion functor induces an equivalence of categories

$$\text{Coh}(X)\simeq\text{Coh}(\mathfrak{X}).$$

> Does it induce an equivalence of étale sites $X_{\rm ét}\simeq\mathfrak{X}_{\rm ét}$, resp. finite étale sites $X_{\rm fét}\simeq\mathfrak{X}_{\rm fét}$?
>   Do their $\ell$-adic cohomologies agree, compatibly with Tate twists?

Comment: Is $\mathfrak{X}$ proper?

Comment: Note that the etale site of $\mathfrak{X}$ is equivalent to the etale site of the special fiber $X_0$, while $X$ has the etale open obtained by inverting $p$. So the etale sites are not equivalent. However, the etale cohomology with torsion coefficients will be the same, by the proper base change theorem.

Comment: I would not expect the topoi to be the same, however the cohomologies will agree in the proper case by Piotr's argument, and in the case where $\mathfrak{X}$ is affine and algebraically of finite type over $\operatorname{spec} \mathbb{Z}_p$ by the same argument but using Gabber's affine analog of proper base change. I think the second case would essentially only be finite extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Your question about the finite etale sites is equivalent to $G$-torsors being representable for finite groups $G$, which I think is true for both etale and adically etale topologies.

Comment: Yes, and the comparison for finite etale (also for the "generic fibers" in some sense) can be seen also using Grothendieck's existence theorem: since if $f \colon Y\to X$ is finite etale, then $Y = {\rm Spec}_X\, \mathcal{A}$ where $\mathcal{A}=f_* \mathcal{O}_Y$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra.

Comment: (See Prop. IV 2.2 in SGA4.5 Arcata. The entire section IV devoted to the (simplified w.r.t. SGA4) proof of the proper base change theorem should be a good inspiration.)